# NestJs: inject service (or anything) into imported module

Tags: dependency-injection, nestjs

Is there a way better than below to inject a service or component inside an imported module?

```js
export interface AmqpInterceptor{
  after(message:any):Promise<void>;
}

export class AmqpInterceptors extends Array<AmqpInterceptor>{

}

//generic library module
@Module({
  providers:[{
    provide: AmqpInterceptors,
    useValue: []
  }]
}
export class AMQPModule implements OnModuleInit{
  static register(options: AMQPOptions): DynamicModule {
    const providers = options.providers || []
    return {
      module: AMQPModule,
      providers: [
        ...providers,
        OtherProvider
      ]
    }
  }
}

//end user module
@Module({
  imports: [
    AMQPModule.register(({
      // I had to create a factory method to pass providers as an argument.
      // I would think that it is not a good practice
      providers: [{
        provide:AmqpInterceptors,
        useValue:[MyCustomInterceptor]
      }]
    })
  ],
  providers: [
    
  ]
})
export class QueueModule {

}
```

Current working solution: I declare a default empty array in the generic module and a factory method that allows to pass custom value in module construction.(In my happiest world I declare multiple instances of an interface and then, DI collects all of these, but I thinks this is really impossible in NestJs)

Comment: You want to inject a service into an imported module A, why dont you create a separate module B that you import in A instead?

Comment: Because I need module A to be agnostic to any extra extra logic. Ie: Anybody who wants to use module A should be able to intercept (monitor, transform, log, trace, etc) messages. And by the time I publish "module A", that code wouldn't even exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a package like [@golevelup/nestjs-discovery](https://github.com/golevelup/nestjs/tree/master/packages/discovery) to help you with.

Basically you've to do the following:

// AMQP Module

// amqp-interceptor.decorator.ts

```js
import { SetMetadata } from '@nestjs/common';

export function AmqpInterceptor() {
  return SetMetadata('AMQP_INTERCEPTOR', true)
}
```

// amqp-explorer.ts

```js
import { OnModuleInit } from '@nestjs/common'

@Injectable()
export class AmqpExplorer implements OnModuleInit {
  constructor(
    private readonly discoveryService: DiscoveryService,
  ) {}

  async onModuleInit(): Promise<void> {
      const amqpInterceptorProviders = await this.discoveryService.providers('AMQP_INTERCEPTOR')

      // you can store this list, to be queried by some
      // other provider to use interceptors, etc.
  }
}
```

// amqp.module.ts

```js
@Module({ providers:[AmqpExplorer]})
export class AMQPModule { }
```

// end user module

// end-user.module.ts

```js
@Module({ imports:[AMQPModule], providers: [SomeAmqpInterceptor] })
export class EndUserModule { }
```

// some-amqp.interceptor.ts

```js
@Injectable()
@AmqpInterceptor()
export class SomeAmqpInterceptor {
  run(): void { console.log('intercepting') }
}
```

Obs:

- Interceptor decorator: you can add any params which would help you to improve your api
- I suggest this (list of providers) instead of injecting decorated providers into your module, because I don't know how do you plan to use them. This way, you've a list of providers and can invoke each one.
- `AMQP_INTERCEPTOR` string can collide with some other metadata, it's a good practice add something more specific to avoid two metadata with same one in a module
- To invoke the interceptors later:

```js
import { ExternalContextCreator } from '@nestjs/core/helpers/external-context-creator'

export class Runner {
  constructor(
    private readonly handler: DiscoveredMethodWithMeta,
    private readonly externalContextCreator: ExternalContextCreator,
  ) { }

  run(): void {
    const handler = this.externalContextCreator.create(
      this.handler.discoveredMethod.parentClass.instance,
      this.handler.discoveredMethod.handler,
      this.handler.discoveredMethod.methodName,
    )

    const handlerResult = await handler(content)
  }
```

- Didn't run local, but I think this is a good way to start

Comment: I think this is a brilliant solution. I guess I can add precedence metadata even (like Spring). Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, it's all about you requirements. And if it solves your question, mark as answered please :D